why weekday() column dax function is not working in direct query mode while I'm connected with databricks

showing this error in direct query mode
DayOfWeek_N = 
SWITCH (
    WEEKDAY ( 'TestData'[Date] ),
    1, "7th",   // Sunday becomes 7th day
    2, "1st",   // Monday becomes 1st day
    3, "2nd",   // Tuesday becomes 2nd day
    4, "3rd",   // Wednesday becomes 3rd day
    5, "4th",   // Thursday becomes 4th day
    6, "5th",   // Friday becomes 5th day
    7, "6th"    // Saturday becomes 6th day
)

I tried with this column dax

Are you using a calendar table?
